# excel vba For each statement

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a For each statement that Populates the

- Num to xlFillValues base on the Quantity
- Num_start xlFillSeries base on the Quantity
- Start_Pallet_Num xlFillValues base on the Quantity/120

```
      Num              Quantity         Num_Start           Start_Pallet_Num
    720XA00000         10000            81000003                1261
```

Comment: What help do you need?  Could you have a read of [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub a()
    quantity = Cells(2, 2).Value
    stcount = 0
    stvalue = Cells(2, 4).Value
    For loop_ctr = 2 To quantity
    Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 1) = Cells(2, 1).Value
    Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 3) = Cells(loop_ctr, 3).Value + 1
    If quantity / 120 > 83 Then
       stcount = stcount + 1
          If stcount = 120 Then
          stvalue = stvalue + 1
          End If
        Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 4) = stvalue
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
    Next loop_ctr
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, and sorry It’s partially worked since I didn’t explain it right. I need my start_pallet_num 1261 to repeat 120 times then add one to the next number 1262 to repeat 120 until it reaches the quantity / 120 which is 83.333

Comment: Sub a()
quantity = Cells(2, 2).Value
stcount = 0
stvalue = Cells(2, 4).Value
For loop_ctr = 2 To quantity
Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 1) = Cells(2, 1).Value
Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 3) = Cells(loop_ctr, 3).Value + 1
If quantity / 120 > 83 Then
   stcount = stcount + 1
      If stcount = 120 Then
      stvalue = stvalue + 1
      End If
    Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 4) = stvalue
End If
counter = counter + 1
Next loop_ctr
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sub a()
    quantity = Cells(2, 2).Value
    stcount = 0
    stvalue = Cells(2, 4).Value
    For loop_ctr = 2 To quantity
    Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 1) = Cells(2, 1).Value
    Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 3) = Cells(loop_ctr, 3).Value + 1
    If quantity / 120 > 83 Then
       stcount = stcount + 1
          If stcount = 120 Then
          stvalue = stvalue + 1
          End If
        Cells(loop_ctr + 1, 4) = stvalue
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
    Next loop_ctr
    End Sub
```

Try this code